# Excel Formatting in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I was asked to do a console application that capable of generating an excel report and send it as an email attachment per month.

The problem arises when the date in the report is not in `'General'` format and is in `'Custom'` format, which is baffling as I didn't change the format. All cells should be in `'General'` format except for phone numbers (I changed it into `'Text'`).

Here is the code when inserting data to excel:

```
foreach(DataRow dataRow in dtRow.Rows)
{
    foreach(var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
    {
       xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 6, 9].NumberFormat = "@";
       xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 6, j + 1] = item;
       j++;
    }
    i++;
    j=0;
}
```

I use SQL Server to get the data and the date data in SQL Server is in this kind of format:

```
02 April 2018 01:52:49
```

And here's an example of the desired result in excel report:

```
02 April 2018 01:52:49
```

While in reality, the result is:

```
4/2/2018 1:52
```

The problem is:

- For February and March reports, I got the desired result without
  formatting through C# code(like this `"02 February 2018 01:52:49"`),
  but for April, I got this instead: `4/2/2018 1:52`, **and I use the

  same code to generate the report.**
- I really don't want to manually format it to Text to achieve the desired result using the NumberFormat. The performance is suffered,    as there are hundreds of data.

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: Well if i paste "02 February 2018 01:52:49" into excel it knows and decides in my case to go with "02/02/2018 01:52" however the @ format turns it into a number of days since 1900 or whenever it is.

Comment: SQL Server does *not* return strings for date values. It returns `DateTime`. If you convert this to a string you'll always have conversion issues. Store a real DateTime in the `Value` property and *don't* try to modify the `NumberFormat`, unless you want to change how that *DateTime* appears

Comment: BTW if you use a library like EPPlus to generate Excel files you can just write `sheet.LoadFromDataTable` or `LoadFromCollection` to load the entire sheet

Comment: FYI, I forgot to tell, I use this to format the date in SQL Server : **CAST(FORMAT(a.CreatedDate, N'dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'id-id')AS VARCHAR)**

Comment: @jarlh because it has something to do with SQL?

Comment: @BugFinder The weird thing is, No problem with February and March Report, It still reads `02 February 2018 01:52:49` or  `02 March 2018 01:52:49`  in the excel file. But in April the date becomes : `4/2/2018 1:52`

Comment: @JemmyGunawan, it has? I can't find anything SQL related.

Comment: The date returned from sql should be an _object_, not a string. Its format is irrelevant. `DateTime` objects themselves only store ticks, not formats.

Comment: @jarlh well, like I said, it has something to do with SQL Server. The date  I used is retrieved from SQL Server. I put the "sql" tag just in case. Besides, I put "C#" and "Excel" first before sql.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the reply! I did consider using EPPlus or ClosedXML, but my mentor won't allow me.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the format of the cells to Text, you can enter a space or an apostrophe before the date. It won't show in the cell.

For example:

```
'02 February 2018 01:52:49
```

Source:
[Stop automatically changing numbers to dates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8)

Also check the recommendation:

> We recommend using an apostrophe instead of a space for entering data
>   if you plan on using lookup functions against the data. Functions like
>   MATCH or VLOOKUP overlook the apostrophe when calculating the results.